# ReactJS Webapp - background changed after inputting

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, web-applications

This is my background before I input something:
[before input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epdrT.png)

And after input:
[after input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBvRZ.png) the background somehow changed unintentionally.

Here is my code:

```
<div
  style={{
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundImage: `url(${mobileBackground})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: `0% 0%`,
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  }}
  className={`flex flex-col items-center ${styles.root}`}
>
...
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably because of the height. Can you give us a bit more context and please explain what is the reasoning behind those styles.

Comment: ahh silly me, I changed ```window.innerHeight``` to ```100vh``` and it worked. I was tried to make the background fullscreen. Thanks yovchokalev!